# Get Selenium performance logs in real time (Java, Kotlin)

Tags: java, selenium, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to get selenium performance logs. I've came across a way to get log entries using the code below:

```
    val loggingPrefs = LoggingPreferences()
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL)

    val capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
    capabilities.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", loggingPrefs)

    driver = RemoteWebDriver(driverService.url, capabilities)

    ...

    val logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

    logEntries.forEach {
        print(it.message)
    }
```

But i'm looking for a way to get those logs in real time like a stream or some callback method so i could process it in real time on another thread or coroutine. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
@Test
public void logTest() {

    new Thread(() -> {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Logs from separate thread: " + driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("Main thread is now sleeping");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```